# script to attach screen and run command but do NOT detach

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -r session -X run 'long-cleanup-and-quit'
doing-something-else
...
```

Which is fine, but I want 'doing-something-else' to wait for screen. screen -X doesn't block, which is understandable.

So is there a way to have `screen -r session -X run 'long-cleanup-and-quit'` attach, run command, but do NOT detach? Eventually the command will terminate the process/screen so the script can continue.

My workaround so far is to just loop for the process and wait.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution by incorporating an answer to a non-screen question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152028/188963

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756584/188963

So, you can do:

```
(base) balter@spectre:~$ cat file123
cat: file123: No such file or directory
(base) balter@spectre:~$ screen -dmS test bash -c "echo 123 > file123; bash"
(base) balter@spectre:~$ cat file123
123
(base) balter@spectre:~$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        13496.test      (05/19/22 12:04:13)     (Detached)
1 Socket in /home/balter/.screen.
```

or

`screen -dmS test bash -c "top; bash"`

When I attach `screen -r test` top is running. When I `q` to kill top, I drop into a bash shell.